# Crash involving UISearchDisplayController rotating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, uisearchbar

My app seems to crash sometimes when I rotate the phone. ViewControllerA has a UISearchDisplayController. ViewControllerA pushes ViewControllerB onto the nav stack.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791d0 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791c0 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000791b2 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0008d6fa abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000059ec _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042df2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000048cc objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0009fa70 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0009ef0e ___forwarding___ + 502
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00031678 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  UIKit                           0x00148194 -[UISearchDisplayController windowWillAnimateRotation:] + 92
14  Foundation                      0x00018fb0 _nsnote_callback + 136
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00069e6c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0001a374 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
17  Foundation                      0x000040bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
18  UIKit                           0x000ed5d0 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:duration:force:] + 3108
19  UIKit                           0x000eee6c -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 44
20  UIKit                           0x0007763c -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 68
21  UIKit                           0x000775b6 -[UIWindow _updateInterfaceOrientationFromDeviceOrientation:] + 106
22  UIKit                           0x00077506 -[UIWindow _handleDeviceOrientationChange:] + 82
23  Foundation                      0x00018fb0 _nsnote_callback + 136
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00069e6c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
25  CoreFoundation                  0x0001a374 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
26  Foundation                      0x000040bc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
27  UIKit                           0x00040582 -[UIDevice setOrientation:animated:] + 138
28  UIKit                           0x0005d670 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 2732
29  UIKit                           0x0005ca56 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
30  UIKit                           0x0005c500 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5016
31  GraphicsServices                0x00004140 PurpleEventCallback + 660
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00071aa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00073848 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00074626 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
35  CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
37  GraphicsServices                0x000036e8 GSEventRunModal + 108
38  GraphicsServices                0x00003794 GSEventRun + 56
39  UIKit                           0x000062a0 -[UIApplication _run] + 396
40  UIKit                           0x00004e10 UIApplicationMain + 664
41  StockTwits                      0x00002d58 0x1000 + 7512
42  StockTwits                      0x00002d28 0x1000 + 7464

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002dc4c kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6e44 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6894 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6a34 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007ad82 _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073fcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001658 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003724 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000722c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00074582 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x00003056 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a986 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000700e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00001658 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00003724 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000722c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00074582 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d8e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0001d7ec CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x0003b71e +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x0000bc96 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000909da __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a986 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x000700e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025a20 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00077e70 __CFSocketManager + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a986 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000700e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007b85c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007ae98 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073fcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3e90724c
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x09ad4aec      r6: 0x2fffda84      r7: 0x2fffda94
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x088ca2d0     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fffda94      lr: 0x352741c7      pc: 0x352741d0
  cpsr: 0x080f0010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a selector that is not implemented.

Best way to dig down is switch to debug mode and actually run with debugger attached. It should stop right away at the correct line, or give the information at the console.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it on device or simulator with the debugger attached. Very hard to nail this! Suggestions?

Comment: What OS version do you have installed on the device? Maybe you use something that is not defined there?